# Complete list of elements in updatePlugins.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a custom plugin for IntelliJ, and I want to have it in my personal repository. Then I looked [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-plugins-to-enterprise-repositories.html) how to create a repository, and basically I need only to create a `updatePlugins.xml` file, that it should contain the following element:

```
<plugin id="MyPlugin" url="http://plugins.example.com:8080/myPlugin.jar" version="1.0"/>
```

and place it in the repository folder/server. Then, when I open IntelliJ IDEA and check the plugin list, I can see mine (once I added my repository to the list). But, I see other plugins have much more information, as for example description, change notes, categories etc...

Following these two links, [plugins list](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/plugin_repository/api/plugins_list.html) and [plugin details](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/plugin_repository/api/plugin_details.html), I get some xml that give me some hint (note that they are different from the `updatePlugins.xml` that I have seen in the official documentation). Using an error-try approach, I was able to reach this state in my `updatePlugins.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
  <plugin id=""
      url=""
      version="">
    <description></description>
    <change-notes></change-notes>
    <vendor email="" url=""></vendor>
    <name></name>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So, I was able to add description, vendor, name and change notes. But something is still missing, for example I was not able to add a Category.

How can I add it? is there somewhere the official complete list of elements that I can use in the `updatePlugins.xml`?

Thanks very much

PS:
Once the plugin is installed, I get more information, taken from the `plugin.xml` and `build.gradle` files present in my project. But, I would like to have this information before downloading it. I suppose I need to use the `updatePlugins.xml` file in order to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation about [updatePlugins.xml](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/update_plugins_format.html) has been added to the IntelliJ Platform SDK.